# Process quitting in Rust

Tags: rust

I decided to make an application that will find the median of any given list of numbers.
I wanted to make an option to quit the process, but when I tested it, the process keeps going.

Whenever I type "q" it should stop, however it does not.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut v1: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();

    loop {
        println!("Enter: ");

        let mut inp: String = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("Failure");
        
        let upd_inp: i32 = match inp.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => if inp == String::from("q") {
                break
            } else {
                continue
            }
        };
        
        v1.push(upd_inp);

        println!("{:?}", v1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `inp` contains the newline, you strip it for parsing but the original variable still contains it. This has answers but I can't find the dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str::trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) doesn't modify the string. It returns a slice of the string (basically, a substring). So even though you did `inp.trim()` on an earlier line, the `inp` being compared in your `if` statement still has a newline at the end. Simply change your comparison to

```
inp.trim() == String::from("q")
```

and the input of `q` will be detected as intended.

Comment: Correction: `.trim()` returns a *slice* of the original String

Comment: Yesterday I tried and it worked perfectly! Thanks a million.